# Android disable passing events to underlying webview

Tags: android, events, webview, touch

I have a TextView displayed on top of a WebView. Both of them are placed inside a RelativeLayout.

Since TextView is displayed on top of a WebView and covers the whole of a WebView I would like to disable passing touch events from TextView to underlying WebView. I don't want touching TextView to cause scrolling in a WebView.

Is that possible in Android? If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can attach a `View.OnTouchListener` on your TextView that returns `true` to prevent propagating touches to the underlying WebView.

```
findViewById(R.id.textview).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // return TRUE since we want to consume the event
    return true; 
  }
});
```

Note that this will prevent all touches on your WebView: scrolls and clicks.